# Adding dependencies changes the target to the first C file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES:

SRC:=../Src
OBJ:=../Obj

# Sources
SOURCES := $(SRC)/App/a.c $(SRC)/App/b.c $(SRC)/App/c.c
HEADERS := $(wildcard $(SRC)/App/*.h)

# Directories
INC_DIRS := $(SRC)/App
OBJ_INC_DIRS := $(INC_DIRS:$(SRC)/%=$(OBJ)/%)

# Objects
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRC)%=$(OBJ)%.obj)

# Dependencies
DEPS := $(SOURCES:$(SRC)%.c=$(OBJ)%.d)
-include $(DEPS)

GCC_INCLUDES := $(foreach directory, $(INC_DIRS), -I$(directory))

all: target

target: $(OBJECTS)
    touch target

#Objects
$(OBJ)%.c.obj: $(SRC)%.c
    @echo Compiling $@
    @touch $@

# Dependencies 
$(OBJ)%.d: $(SRC)%.c
    @echo Checking dependencies for $<
    @gcc -MM $< $(GCC_INCLUDES) -MT '$(patsubst %.d,%.c.obj,$@)' -MT '$@' -MF '$@'
    @[ ! -s $@ ] && rm -f $@

# Creating directory tree before checking dependencies    
$(DEPS):|$(OBJ_INC_DIRS)

$(OBJ_INC_DIRS):
    @mkdir $@

clean:
    echo clean
    @rm $(OBJ_INC_DIRS)
```

When running the first time, I get:

```
Checking dependencies for ../Src/App/a.c
Checking dependencies for ../Src/App/b.c
Checking dependencies for ../Src/App/c.c
clean
Compiling ../Obj/App/a.c.obj
Compiling ../Obj/App/b.c.obj
Compiling ../Obj/App/c.c.obj
touch target
```

It's ok, but now, make again (without modifying any file):

```
make: `../Obj/App/a.c.obj' is up to date.
```

Now if I modify the file a.c

```
Checking dependencies for ../Src/App/a.c
Compiling ../Obj/App/a.c.obj
```

`target` isn't remade !

It's like my file a.c is the target but it isn't... Can someone explain me what's wrong here?

If I remove the include to the DEPS, I observe the expected behavior...

Thanks

---

### EDIT

By putting the include at the end as mentioned by @Beta works but now I added the target clean and show the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have to do some experiments to be sure, but I think the problem is:

```
-include $(DEPS)
...
all: target
```

You include `$(DEPS)` *before* the first target. So if you modify `a.c`, Make sees that it must rebuild `a.d`, then since it `includes` that file it must start over, and now `a.c.obj` is an earlier target than `all`.

Try moving `-include $(DEPS)` to the end of the makefile.

**EDIT:**
(Two small points: your `clean` rule is incorrect, since it tries to `rm` a directory, and I would do `make clean; make all` rather than `make all`, since I am not certain that Make promises to build targets in the given order in all cases.)

Yes, this makefile will rebuild the `DEPS` even when running `clean`. The makefile `includes` those files and has a rule for them, so if they are missing or out of date it must rebuild them and restart, *no matter what the target is*. The best way to deal with this is by [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html); basically, the commands that build dependency files go in the `%.obj` rule, so that `a.d` is a side effect of building `a.c.obj`. It's a sophisticated technique, not obvious, but it works beautifully. (Let us know if you try this and have trouble setting it up.)

Comment: please consider my edit. Your solution works fine, except when I do an `make clean all` because dependencies will be generated before the clean...